# Python List slicing does not work in my guessing game

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to create a game where the user imagines a number from 1 - 20 and the computer tries to guess it.
For this purpose:
1. I created a list of all numbers from 1 - 20.
2. The program chooses a random number from the list and asks if the imaginary number is smaller or bigger than the random number.
3. The user answers with 'j' or 'n'
4. After each guess, the list is sliced from the redundant numbers
5. Eventually, only one number should be in the list and the computer should conclude the right number.
Code:

```
import random
d = list(range(1,21))
tries = []
while True:
    if len(d) > 1:
        x = random.choice(d)
        tries.append(1)
        print(f"Is your number bigger than {x}?")
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'j':
            del d[:x]
            print(d)
        if answer == 'n':
            del d[x:]
            print(d)
        tries.append(1)
        x = random.choice(d)
        print(f"Is your number smaller than {x}?")
        answer = input()
        if answer == 'j':
            del d[x-1:]
            print(d)
        if answer == 'n':
            del d[:x-1]
            print(d)
    else:
        print(f"Your number is {d[0]}. You guessed with {len(tries)} attempts.")
        break
```

However, weirdly the slicing doesn't work correctly, I've encountered multiple times an outcome like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51mV8.png)

As you can see, after I confirmed my number is smaller than 9, it does not delete the numbers from 9-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices of the list change as your list shrinks; you can find the index with `i = d.index(x)` :

```
import random
d = list(range(1,21))
tries = []
while True:
    if len(d) > 1:
        x = random.choice(d)
        tries.append(1)
        print(f"Is your number bigger than {x}?")
        answer = input()
        i = d.index(x)
        if answer == 'j':
            del d[:i+1]
        if answer == 'n':
            del d[i+1:]
        print(d)
        tries.append(1)
        x = random.choice(d)
        print(f"Is your number smaller than {x}?")
        answer = input()
        i = d.index(x)
        if answer == 'j':
            del d[i:]
        if answer == 'n':
            del d[:i]
        print(d)
    else:
        print(f"Your number is {d[0]}. You guessed with {len(tries)} attempts.")
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not slice with the index but with the content of your list. Try this to find your index:

```py
del[:d.index(x)]
```

Also you do not need a while and an if statement with an break.
Just use while like this.

```py
while len(d) > 1:
    pass
    # some more code
else:
    print(f"Your number is {d[0]}. You guessed with {len(tries)} attempts.")
```

Also don't use a list and append on. Eiter append the number guessed or just use an increment counter `tries = 0/tries += 1`.

The complete code could look like this.
Your code also needs always tow trys even if you only have on choice left.
Than you should limit qestions that give now answer of value.
`x = random.choice(d[:-1])` and `x = random.choice(d[1:])`

```py
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = list(range(1, 21))
    tries = 0
    while len(d) > 1:
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            x = random.choice(d[:-1])
            tries += 1
            print(f"Is your number bigger than {x}?")
            answer = input("Type: j/n\n")
            while answer != "j" and answer != "n":
                answer = input("Type: j/n\n")
            if answer == 'j':
                del d[:d.index(x) + 1]
                print(d)
            else:
                del d[d.index(x) + 1:]
                print(d)
        else:
            tries += 1
            x = random.choice(d[1:])
            print(f"Is your number smaller than {x}?")
            answer = input("Type: j/n\n")
            while answer != "j" and answer != "n":
                answer = input("Type: j/n\n")
            if answer == 'j':
                del d[d.index(x):]
                print(d)
            else:
                del d[:d.index(x)]
                print(d)
    else:
        print(f"Your number is {d[0]}. You guessed with {tries} attempts.")
```